# Дизайн приложения для Андроид

Tags: android-sdk, android

Привет!

Прочитал руководство на [офф. сайте](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) и никак не могу понять самого простого, а именно:

В проекте есть папки **ldpi**, **mdpi**, **hdpi**, **xhdpi** в какую из папок и какого размера необходимо добавить рисунок (фон приложения), чтобы на всех устройствах выглядело как надо. Насколько я догадываюсь рисунок размером 320 × 480 px помещается в папку **mdpi**.

Объясните, пожалуйста. А еще лучше покажите небольшой пример или дайте ссылочку где об этом пусть и не кратко, но доходчиво и на примерах объясняют.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для создания этих изображений вы должны начать с исходного изображения в векторном формате и генерировать изображения для каждой плотности, используя следующую шкалу размеров:

- **xhdpi:** 2.0,
- **hdpi:** 1.5,
- **mdpi:** 1.0 (базовый),
- **ldpi:** 0.75.

Подробней тут: [поддержка различных плотностей экрана](http://anddev.ru/66/podderzhka-razlichnyih-plotnostey-ekrana-supporting-different-densities.html).

Comment: Хмм...интересно, сейчас гляну. Спасибо.

Comment: Ни знаю почему, но кто то удаляет ссылки на файлы. Попробуем еще раз.

[Google Android программирование для мобильных устройств][1]


  [1]: http://depositfiles.com/files/vebpxug6b?redirect

Answer (score 0):

1. dpi - означает dot per inch то бишь "точек на дюйм" и не имеет прямого отношения к размеру экрана...
2. Масштабирование вашего фона будет производиться системой в зависимости от dpi текущего устройства. Для масштабирования как раз и будет выбираться битмап из соответствующего каталога.

Ссылка [здесь](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Спасибо, конечно. Но я знаю про эту ссылку и указал ее выше и именно руководство описанное там я считаю не внятным (это субъективное мнение). И я знаю что означает dpi. Меня волнует конкретно вопрос этих папок ( ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi). Т.к система ничего автоматически не определит, если я правильно не разложу изображения по папкам. И меня интересует как раз, какого размера изображения мне необходимо вложить в ту или иную папку.